# How to disable only weekends in Laravel-Filamentphp or disable all dates except the requested ones

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

I'm working on a Laravel project using Filamentphp
My form has DatePicker and I'm unable to disable all Weekends days or disable all dates except the one I specify.
[image]

```
 DatePicker::make('issue_start_date')
                              ->required()
                              ->reactive()
                              ->weekStartsOnSunday()
                              ->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set, $state)
                              {
                                  $month = date('M', strtotime($state));
                                  $year  = date('Y', strtotime($state));
                                  ($month == null || $year === null)
                                      ? $set('name', null)
                                      : $set('name', $month . ' ' . $year);
                              })
                              ->dehydrateStateUsing(function (callable $set, $state)
                              {
                                  if ($state === null) $set('name', null);
                              }),
```

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use `disabledDates` option to disable dates based on the requirements.

below is an example of **disabledDates**

```
DatePicker::make('issue_start_date')
    ->required()
    ->reactive()
    ->weekStartsOnSunday()
    ->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set, $state)
    {
        $month = date('M', strtotime($state));
        $year  = date('Y', strtotime($state));
        ($month == null || $year === null)
            ? $set('name', null)
            : $set('name', $month . ' ' . $year);
    })
    ->dehydrateStateUsing(function (callable $set, $state)
    {
        if ($state === null) $set('name', null);
    })
    ->disabledDates([
        // Disable all weekends
        'Sat', 'Sun',
        // Disable dates before today
        'before ' . now()->format('Y-m-d'),
        // Disable dates after 5 days from now
        'after ' . now()->addDays(5)->format('Y-m-d'),
    ]);
```

You can disable all weekends in the Filamentphp calendar by using the events function in your calendar configuration. This function allows you to add custom events to the calendar, including disabling specific dates.

```
->events([
    [
        'title' => 'Weekend',
        'start' => Carbon::parse('saturday'),
        'end' => Carbon::parse('sunday'),
        'display' => 'background',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I added "disableDates" to my code as requested. but didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have  `'Sat', 'Sun'` is disabled?

Comment: When using ['Sat', 'Sun'] nothing disables. But when using [ 'before ' . now()->format('Y-m-d'), 'after ' . now()->addDays(5)->format('Y-m-d')], only the current date 5th day from the current date is disabled not the range of dates

Comment: You can modify the `disabledDates()` and` disabledDateRanges()` methods to disable specific dates or ranges according to your needs.

Comment: How do I disable all weekends in my calendar?